# Jquery AddClass to a specific class

Tags: jquery, selector, addclass

I'm new in jQuery and my question is probably obvious for most of you.

I want to add a class to a specific class

in short, my page has the following tags:

```
<div class="content">
   blabla   1111
    <a href="#" id="1">Test link</a>
</div>
<div class="content">
   blabla  2222
    <a href="#" id="1">Test link</a>
</div>
```

when I click on one of the link  I want to add a class just below it.

so if click on the first link, I want to add a class comment

the jQuery command   `$(content).addclass("comment")`  of course create the comment class below the both div class content,  I want only to add below the clicked link.

Comment: Aside: Your `id`s on your `<a>` elements are non-unique. The `id` attribute on any element must be a unique value from any other `id` attribute on the page.

Comment: What do you mean by add a class below the link? You add classes to elements, so which element should get the class?

Comment: What do you mean "add a class just below it"? Do you mean you want to create another element with the class "comment"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$(this)` to target current clicked element:

```
$('.content').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('comment');
});
```

Also `id` is unique, you should use class for your anchors instead.

If you want to add class comment on `.content` div when click on the anchor than you can use:

```
$('.content a').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.content').addClass('comment');
})
```

Comment: Thanks , it works but I'll have another question , I'll post a new one.

Answer (score 0):

When the link is clicked select the next element after the parent element.

```
$("a").click(function(){
    $(this).parent(".content").next(".content").addClass('comment');
});
```